# Why regex.Match is returning empty string?

Tags: regex, vb.net

[image]

I just want to get the part of string that matches the regular expression but trying with match.Value or with groups it always returns "". It's driving me crazy.
EDIT:

This worked:

```
Private Function NormalizeValue(ByVal fieldValue As String) As String
    Dim result As String = ""
    Dim pattern As String = "[a-zA-Zñ'-]*"
    Dim matches As Match
    matches = Regex.Match(fieldValue, pattern)
    While (matches.Success = True)
        result = result & matches.Value
        matches = matches.NextMatch()
    End While
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Screenshots of your code = not cool; paste as text and use the code formatter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your regex starts with ^ and ends with $, you are trying to match the whole string - not a part as your are stating in the question.
So you either need to remove them or rephrase your question.